# How do I unlock my Tablet (using a pattern lock) when there is no "Forgot Password" button?

Tags: lock-screens, password, locked-out, pattern-lock

I forgot the password for my account on my brother's tablet, and being that it is not mine I cannot factory reset it, and even after about 100 failed password attempts, there is no "Forgot Password" option.

Comment: Did you ask your brother?

Comment: What device is it? OS version?

Answer (score 0):

Back up data etc using the restore function obviously on a SD card!then remove card and perform factory reset and after phone is set up then restore data or restore data on computer isim USB cable!my thoughts

Comment: If you read the question you will see that it states there is no factory reset option